# How to describe spin-orbital coupling in Weyl semi-metal

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, topological-insulators

In three dimensional Weyl semi-metal, the Hamiltonian that describes low excitation quasi-particle is well-know Weyl Hamiltonian: +/- $k\cdot\sigma$. But if I want to add spin-orbital coupling in that effective Hamiltonian, what should that part looks like? Thanks.

Comment: Within that low-energy space (two band touching) and at the linear order in $k$, no other terms can be added.

Comment: @MengCheng Hi, Meng. Thanks for your reply. But what if we lose that limitation and can add higher order of k? In real material, higher orders must exist. And I am thinking about those effects. :)